# OnClick or OnHover Event Listen For All IMG in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, events, onclick, listen

I have a list of images 
I would like to listen for click actions or hover actions on any "img" on my page regarless of ID. And I want to use regular javascript and be friendly with modern browsers.

I have done a lot of research and reading but I have yet to find a solution.
I am thinking that my code might look something like this but I'm not positive:

```
var allimg = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < allimg.length; ++i) {
   // do something
}
```

How do I add onlick to this, do I need to call it as a function on pageload?  how do I have the javascript react to all img tags when clicked?

Answer (score 4):

Use event delegation:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName === "IMG") {
        console.log('do something');
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNpZn/)

Answer (score 0):

any chance you might have jQuery?  If so...

```
$(img).on('click',function(e){
  console.log('rad')
});
```

otherwise.. you are on the right track. Untested but this should get you there...

```
function clickHandler(e){
  console.log('I love goats')   
}

var allimg = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < allimg.length; ++i) {
  allimg[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No use adding listeners to every element.  Try this inside your loop.  `allimg[i].onclick/onmouseover = function(){//your code}`